# LinkedIn Featured image not displaying

Tags: linkedin

In our own LinkedIn profile there's a Featured section.

In that section, it's possible to add Posts, Articles, Links and Media.

Added more than one Link and the image showed like I wanted.

Thing is, when it came to add my own weblog, https://weblog.tiagoperes.eu/ , i get the following

[image: LinkedIn add Featured Link problem with Image]

Changed the Title and Description and clicked the "Save" button.

With this i got the following

[image]

Did some research in LinkedIn help forum but could only reach [this relevant link](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/forum/question/10277026). In here, a moderator says

> When adding a URL link to the featured section of your profile, an
>   image will not be shown with the website. When entering a URL it will
>   pull any text associated with the URL link. For example if you add the
>   LinkedIn website it will display the text associated with the URL but
>   no image.

Thing is, that doesn't make sense because all the other links work fine (and one of the links is also to one of my WordPress websites).

I've tested the same process in a different browser where no previous login was made (just in case cache was a problem), and still got the same problem.

Also, as the website I try to add is made with WordPress and I have the control of it, tested to add a featured image to the Homepage, as you can see next, but also didn't work

[image: WordPress Weblog Featured Image]

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your website is in WordPress, you can do it by using [YoastSEO](https://yoast.com/help/why-doesnt-facebook-display-an-image/).

The hyperlink above redirects you to a page on how to do it using Facebook, however, as [LinkedIn also uses Open Graph metadata](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687), the data used in the Facebook preview is also what LinkedIn will use.

In order to set up an Open Graph image for individual posts and pages, with Yoast SEO,

> you can do that in the Social tab of the Yoast SEO meta box, which can
> be found bellow the page content

(as seen on the image bellow):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used the metadata mentioned at the [LinkedIn Q&A](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687)

Just use below codes between your index.html `<head></head>` tag:

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article'/>
```

Comment: Where is the LinkedIn Q&A link?

Comment: @serenesat Just click on the link and it will take you to the Q&A page on LinkedIn

Answer (score -1):

For the featured image your minimum image dimension should be 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels. If you use a lower dimension LinkedIn will parse another image with a bigger resolution.